# Pivote SQL Server en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Calcula_Ventas_Semana] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fechaini INT,
    @fechafin INT,
    @id_almacen int 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
      @mes NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';


-- select las semanas del mes

SET @mes = 'SELECT 
                SUBSTRING (semana_bono, 3, 3) 
            FROM 
                DWBadamaxRetail.dim.calendario 
            WHERE 
                id_calendario = @fechaini';


SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(semana_bono) + ','
FROM 
    DWBadamaxRetail.dim.calendario 
WHERE 
    id_calendario >= @fechaini AND id_calendario <= @fechafin AND semana_bono like '%'+@mes+'%' 
GROUP BY semana_bono 
ORDER BY 
    semana_bono;

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

-- construct dynamic SQL

SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        e.id_empleado, 
        cod_empleado,
        e.des_empleado,
        e.cargo, 
        sum(v.venta) as venta,
        c.semana_bono  
    FROM 
        DWBadamaxRetail.fact.venta v
        INNER JOIN DWBadamaxRetail.dim.empleado e ON e.id_empleado = v.id_empleado
        INNER JOIN DWBadamaxRetail.dim.calendario c ON c.id_calendario = v.id_calendario 
    WHERE v.id_almacen = @id_almacen  
        AND v.id_calendario >= @fechaini AND v.id_calendario <= @fechafin 
        AND e.cod_empleado <> ''-1'' 
    GROUP BY e.id_empleado, c.semana_bono, des_empleado, cod_empleado, cargo   

    ) T 
PIVOT(
    sum(venta)   
    FOR semana_bono IN ('+ @columns +')
) AS pivot_table;';

PRINT @sql; 
-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

Usando la propiedad pivote para asegurarme de agrupar ventas y ventas por las semanas del mes que pueden ser 4 o 5. Sin embargo, al ejecutar el sp me da el siguiente error:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Procedure Calcula_Ventas_Semana, Line 45 [Batch Start Line 2]
Se pasó un parámetro de longitud no válido a la función LEFT o SUBSTRING.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 17
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@id_almacen".
```

Pero ya he declarado la variable @id_almacen  no puedo ver el error

Comment: Si la consulta donde llenas la variable `@columns` no devuelve resultados, `len(@columns)` devuelve 0, por lo que estás pasando `-1` a `len()`, y ese valor es inválido. Eso explica el primer error.

Answer (score 4):

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Procedure Calcula_Ventas_Semana, Line 45
>   [Batch Start Line 2] Se pasó un parámetro de longitud no válido a la
>   función LEFT o SUBSTRING.

Este error se origina por que estás pasando una longitud negativa en el `LEFT`, por ejemplo si `@columns` fuera blanco, la longitud de esta variable sería 0 y al hacer `LEN(@columns) - 1` el resultado obviamente será `-1`.

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 17 Debe declarar la variable escalar
>   "@id_almacen".

Es cierto que has declarado `@id_almacen`, pero en el cuerpo del SP. El problema es la invocación del código mediante `sp_executesql`, el código `@sql` ejecutado está en un "scope" distinto al del Sp, por lo que es necesario pasar (y declarar) el parámetro que vas a usar. Sería algo así:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
       N'@id_almacen INT, @fechafin DATETIME',
       @id_almacen,
       @fechafin
```

Comment: Y así con este ejemplo, hay que enviar las otras variables como parámetros o seguirán apareciendo errores.

Comment: Efectivamente @LuisCazares! corregido.

Answer (score 0):

Si la columna semana_bono tiene valores NULL o '' (nada) te dará error.

Parece que es la única columna con LEFT o SUBSTRING, así que uno de los errores debe encontrarse ahí.

En cuanto al segundo error, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750548/sql-server-variable-declared-but-still-says-must-declare-the-scalar-variable) puedes ver un caso parecido.

En resumen, el EXECUTE sp_executesql se crea en una sesión diferente, en la cual no existe la variable @id_almacen.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/170312)

Comment: Por cierto el comentario pertinente de @PaperBirdMaster aplica a la primera edición de tu respuesta que era más un comentario que una respuesta. Ahora, luego de tu edición, ya tiene otro color.